# I want to find the last occurrence of a value in an array and also return "-1" if no such number is found

Tags: java

I know there are similar questions on stackoverflow, but none of their answers incorporated a return "-1" when no number is found.

Given an array list such as a = [4, 3, 9, 4, 6]

When entering a value such as v = 4, I want Java to give me the last index equivalent to that value in the array. So in this case, Java should return the index value 3.

If no values exist in the array such as v = 2, then I want it to return "-1".

This following solution I came up with finds the first index and returns it:

```
public static int lastIndexOf(int[] a, int v) {
    int index = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<a.length;i++) {
        if(a[i]==v) {
            index=i;
            return index;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This other solution I have, finds the last index in the array, but does not return "-1" when I enter a value that doesn't exist in the array.

```
public static int lastIndexOf(int[] a, int v) {
    int index = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<a.length;i++) {
        if(a[i]==v) {
            index=i;
        }
    }
    return index;
}
```

I feel like I'm close to solving this, but I can't quite figure out how to mix these two solutions together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the second solution, just initialize the variable like this:

```
int index = -1;
```

Also consider traversing the array from right to left, in this way we can stop as soon as we find the element, it'll be more efficient:

```
public static int lastIndexOf(int[] a, int v) {
    for (int i = a.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
        if (a[i] == v)
            return i;
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assing `int index = -1`. Also a small optimization, loop from end, may be much faster for bigger loops:

```
public static int lastIndexOf(int[] a, int v) {
  int index = -1;
  for(int i=a.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if(a[i]==v) {
        index=i;
        return index;
    }
  }
  return index;
}
```